# Display_expression function on QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, function

I would like to know what exactly do the function `display_expression` introduced in QGIS since version 3.14.

The 3.14 Changelog is not clear on it and also reading the [GitHub commit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35211) didn't help me to solve my doubts about the use of this function.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns the expression used in the Display tab of the layer properties.

Comment: Actually, the answer gave me the requested information. I wasn't connecting the display in the name with the Display Tab. Thanks Gabriel De Luca

Comment: You are welcome @ValP. I don't know about the use of the display tab and can't improve my answer yet, but had seen that the function returns that expression.

Comment: The obvious test was use the function in the expression of the display tab and try to identify a feature..